# how to change website layout using joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I'm totally new to Joomla. Now I have a website developed using joomla.Now I'm wondering on how to modify or reposition the layout of the website.
I'm just wondering do I have to access the css folder of joomla to get it done ?

Kindly advise me,Thank you.

Comment: [create template](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-builds/create-a-template-with-joomla-step-by-step/) ??

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is create a template as you need to change the UI. Please refer this [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-builds/create-a-template-with-joomla-step-by-step/) to get started with Joomla templates. Also read this [links](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template) too. If you google you will find many more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla layout is controlled via templates and there are a few different site templates included when you install Joomla initially. Additional free or commercial templates can be installed if needed.

The active site template is shown at Extensions -> Template Manager.

Lay out your content using the template main body and module positions.

To preview the module positions supplied with a template, go to Extensions -> Template Manager and set the template to the default. Set Extensions -> Template Manager -> Options -> Preview Module Positions to "Enabled" and then browse to www.yourwebsitename.com/index.php?tp=1

You may also be able to find the avaiable module positions documented on the website of the template developer.

You shouldn't have to change any CSS files for basic changes to the layout.